# Postgres won't start after restore point

Tags: windows, restore, postgresql

i'm having a problem with postgresql. Everything was working fine until my computer crashed and windows did a restore checkpoint thing. After that it was a nightmare. Normally I would start postgresql by a bat file I created with the following line:

> NET START postgresql-x64-9.3

In the past this worked, but not anymore. Bow I get the message

> The service name is invalid.  More help is available by typing NET
>   HELPMSG 2185.

I've checked my log files, but I can't find anything, this is the newest log file I've got (It's from yesterday).

```
2015-01-04 08:49:25 CET LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-01-03 18:16:45 CET
2015-01-04 08:49:25 CET FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2015-01-04 08:49:26 CET FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2015-01-04 08:49:27 CET FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2015-01-04 08:49:28 CET FATAL:  the database system is starting up
2015-01-04 08:49:29 CET LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2015-01-04 08:49:29 CET LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2015-01-04 13:01:28 CET LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2015-01-04 13:01:28 CET LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2015-01-04 13:01:28 CET LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2015-01-04 13:01:28 CET LOG:  shutting down
2015-01-04 13:01:28 CET LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Can anyone help me getting postgres to work again? Thanks in advance.

Using windows 7 64 bit ultimate and postgres 9.3 64 bit.

Comment: Check the service logs in Event Viewer too; looks kind of like it's just timing out. Also try setting `log_min_messages = debug1` in `postgresql.conf` and trying again then posting the full log somewhere and posting a link here.